# $X_n=\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}+\frac{n+2}{n^2+2}+\frac{n+3}{n^2+3}+\dots+ \frac{n+n}{n^2+n} $ is bounded above?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$X_n=\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}+\frac{n+2}{n^2+2}+\frac{n+3}{n^2+3}+\dots+ \frac{n+n}{n^2+n} $ is bounded above?

I tried this:

$X_n=\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}+\frac{n+2}{n^2+2}+\frac{n+3}{n^2+3}+\dots+ \frac{n+n}{n^2+n} \leqslant \frac{n+1}{n^2}+\frac{n+2}{n^2}+\frac{n+3}{n^2}+\dots+ \frac{n+n}{n^2+n}$

$= \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k + \frac{n^2}{n^2}$

$=\frac{1}{n^2}\frac{(n+1)(n)}{2}+1$

$= \frac{n+1}{2n}+1= \frac{n}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n}+1=\frac{1}{2}+1+\frac{1}{2n}=\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}$

I'm really not sure if I did it right, can someone help me? How can I conclude it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already proved $X_n \le \dfrac{3}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2n}$ for all integers $n \ge 1$. Now, note  that $\dfrac{1}{2n} \le \dfrac{1}{2}$ for all integers $n \ge 1$. Hence, $X_n \le \dfrac{3}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2n} \le \dfrac{3}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2} = 2$ for all integers $n \ge 1$.

Comment: OKAY! the final part was confusing me because I didn't know if I had to show that 1 / n is bounded

Comment: Depending on what class this is for and what exactly is considered "trivial", you might have to prove that $1/n \le 1$ for all integers $n \ge 1$, but that should be easy.

Answer (score 1):

The boundedness could also be shown quite directly:

$$X_n =\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n+k}{n^2+k}\leq\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2n}{n^2} = 2$$

Answer (score 0):

You can also have the explicit solution

$$x_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n+k}{n^2+k}=n+(n-1) n \left(H_{n^2}-H_{n^2+n}\right)$$

Using asymptotics of harmonic numbers and continuing with Taylor expansions
$$x_n=\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{3 n}-\frac{5}{12 n^2}+\frac{23}{60
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ and you could generate very sharp upper and lower bounds.